# Continuity of the function $f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Show that $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+2xy$ and continuous at $x=0$.

I really don't know where to start..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and consider:
$$\lim_{h\to0}f(x+h)=\lim_{h\to0}f(x)+f(h)+2xh;$$
use continuity of $f$ at $0$.

Comment: So the limit of f(x+h) minus f(h) is less than epsilon? That's how I would show?

Comment: Yes, that works. More directly, $\lim_{h\to0}f(x+h)=\lim_{h\to0}f(x)+f(h)+2xh=f(x)+f(0)$; you need to additionally show $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I am still confused... How does that work? Shouldn't I state that the difference between x and c is less than delta?

Comment: Ahhh... Now it's clearer Thank you very much!